# Getting 301 after upgrading http to https

Tags: nginx

I am trying to serve a static index html and would upgrade http request to https. Let's say that the file below is bursan. Weirdly so when I have another file, pointing to another domain name, siosan but I managed to get it working. For bursan, I keep getting 301s.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bursan.co.uk;
    return 301 https://bursan.co.uk$request_uri;
}


server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html/bursan;
    index index.html;

    server_name bursan.co.uk;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bursan.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/bursan.key;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    # Set up preferred protocols and ciphers. TLS1.2 is required for HTTP/2
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    # This is a cache for SSL connections
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:2m;
    ssl_session_timeout 60m;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Comment: The configuration file works flawlessly. The problem was that I was using Cloudflare and need to change security to Full(Strict), then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
listen 443 ssl default_server;
```

instead of

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

(don't forget to reload the conf and to test it with incognito window to avoid cache issues)